# Is there a way to access the user's own address book data (first & last name, e-mail) in iOS?

Tags: ios, addressbook

I want to prefill some input fields in an app's registration process in order to make it more seamless. Is there a (Apple authorized) way to access this data?

Thanks,
Georg

Comment: If you could show what you have tried along with some sample code that is giving you trouble.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, what you want to do is an often requested feature, but for reasons unknown (probably security related) there is no way to even determine if the phone's owner has an address book entry. I suggest you go to bugreporter.apple.com and ask for this feature (as many of us already have!)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to pre fill the values from your device's address books. If so you have to dig your head into AddressBook Framework in order to access the contact details. Below link is from iOS developer link

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AddressBookUI/Reference/AddressBookUI_Framework/_index.html

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AddressBook/Reference/AddressBook_iPhoneOS_Framework/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007212